# Emacs macro that only fires on non-empty lines

Tags: emacs, macros

Generally, I find myself writing short macros that, e.g. add or remove line comments or correct indentation on a line.

However, with whitespace-mode enabled, I will still have to look out not to fire these macros on blank lines; if the macro tries to delete a character on an empty line, generally it will mess up the entire document.

Is there any solution to this problem which does not involve having some amount of spaces on blank lines, or otherwise altering my document structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `C-M-s ^.` at the beginning of the macro. That is, search for a line that contains at least one character.

Comment: Doesn't white space count as characters?  Maybe something like this: `^[^ ]`, would work instead.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the [legoscia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353374/788700) -- here's a version which also notifies if there's no previous line at all:

```lisp
(defun goto-first-previous-non-empty-line ()
  (interactive)
    (if (re-search-backward "^." nil t)
        (message "First previous non-empty line")
      (message "Beginning of buffer")
      )
    )
```